# Passing value as array in Where clause in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1

I have an array in `$qids` as 
`[{"qid":1},{"qid":2},{"qid":3},{"qid":4}]`, Now, I want to get rows from database matching these `qid` value. I am working on my Laravel project and the where clause I am using is as follows

```
$questions = Question::where(function($q) use ($qids){
    foreach($qids as $key => $value){
        $q->where($key, '=', $value);
    }
})->get();
```

This gives me an error

```
*SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `questions` where (`0` = {"qid":1} and `1` = {"qid":2} and `2` = {"qid":3} and `3` = {"qid":4}))*
```

As I can see, in the error line

```
where (`0` = {"qid":1} and `1` = {"qid":2} and `2` = {"qid":3} and `3` = {"qid":4})
```

it is taking 0, 1, 2, 3 as key and whole {"qid":1} as value.

FYI, I am generating `$qids` from the statement.

```
$qids = Examquestion::select('qid')->where('examid', $examid)->get();
```

is there any way that I could save only values in `$qids` rather than pair. 
Hope you understand the scenario. TIA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this instead

```
$qids = Examquestion::where('examid', $examid)->lists('qid');
```

then use this array in

```
$questions = Question::whereIn('qid', $qids)->get();
```

you'll get your result

Comment: Use method "pluck", lists is removed in Laravel 5.3. Change lists('qid') to pluck('qid')->all()

Answer (score 2):

Associative array format you give is wrong :

i try with below eg ...its work fine for me.

**$qids = array("a"=>"Apples", "b"=>"Oranges", "c"=>"Pears");**

```
    $questions = Question::where(function($q) use ($qids)
{
   foreach($qids as $key => $value)
   {

    $q->where($key, '=', $value);
   }
})->get();
```

Comment: You use :[{"qid":1},{"qid":2},{"qid":3},{"qid":4}]

Comment: So, mine was not assoc. I get that now. But still, How can I make it work?

Comment: $qids =User::where('user_type', '6')->lists('id', 'name')->toArray();             Use lists instead of get along with toArray

Answer (score 2):

As `qid` is repetitive and, therefore, redundant, you could flatten the array, and use a `whereIn` clause:

```php
Question::whereIn('qid', array_flatten($qids));
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone. I got my code working by your help. Here my working code snippet.

```
$qids = Examquestion::select('qid')->where('examid', $examid)->lists('qid');
$questions = Question::select('qid','question','answer','option1','option2','option3','hint')
             ->whereIn('qid', $qids)
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Case:When you have to array in where condition, and you may face case sensation issue($option is array,for case sensation BINARY used):-

`$option = DB::table('test_results')->whereIn('user_id',$form_id)->pluck('answer');`
`$answer = Db::table('answer_keys')->whereIn(DB::raw('BINARY 'option''), $option)->get('answer');`